# Как включить пустые строки в результат String.split?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, парсер

Есть набор строк от внешнего сервиса, вот пример одной из них:

**"||08:29:2017|08:29:2017|160|UMC MED|AAA Doctors Corporation|7,411.50|From Customer|Submitted|08292017|16:00:09|In-Process|||"**

в этой строке 16 полей(значений). Эти значения разделяются символом "|".
С помощью метода `split("//|")` в случае этой строки получаю массивы из 13 полей

**[, , 08:29:2017, 08:29:2017, 160, UMC MED, AAA Doctors Corporation, 5,560.50, From Customer, Submitted, 08292017, 16:00:09, In-Process]**

А в случае этой строки

**"0000005691_1503040276730||08:18:2017|08:24:2017|0000005691|MS547TermUponAppAH||14.74|From Customer|Cleared|08292017|00:00:01|Cleared|POS|P70|VALIDATED"**

получаю нужный результат — 16 значений.

Подскажите, как и чем парсить чтобы не упускать пустые значения?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Использовать дополнительный аргумент метода split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "||08:29:2017|08:29:2017|160|UMC MED|AAA Doctors Corporation|7,411.50|From Customer|Submitted|08292017|16:00:09|In-Process|||";
    System.out.println(str.split("\\|", -1).length);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, умнейший Вы Человек!)